Preconditions in Jira X-Ray, how are they linked to a test?
I'm looking to migrate test cases from TestRail to Jira X-Ray using the JIRA API.
Creating individual tests and preconditions using the API is fine, however, I can't see how the two are linked.
Preconditions don't appear to have any linked issues when I view the XML for both issue types.
I can see that X-Ray provide an API to potentially achieve this, but looks to be limited to the server version and not cloud (which we have).
Has anyone tried to add Preconditions via the JIRA API or know how X-Ray have linked these things together?

Xray has a tutorial that covers the migration from Testrail: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Importing+TestRail+test+cases+using+Test+Case+Importer.
You have examples of migrating tests with preconditions and code available in github.

Hi Cristiano, thanks for pointing me in the direction of the importer. I did go through and use the importer previously (thanks for providing this on github by the way). Unfortunately, it doesn't pull out the preconditions from the XML that I'm using. So I think I may need to debug the converter script to see why it's not picking them up correctly. I was hoping to be able to do achieve the same result using the JIRA API, but can't see how X-RAY have tied everything together.

If you provide the Testrail output file (attach in this thread) I can help checking why the preconditions are not processed.
